# Epson print-scan-copy-fax for Catalina

Tags: catalina, fax

Which Epson print-scan-copy-fax machines give you a plug-and-play experience in Catalina?  Including paperless fax sending and receiving?

I suspect there must be some because /Library/Printers/EPSON/Fax includes, besides frameworks and such, two apps.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: What research have you done thus far and what are you having difficulty with?

Comment: None, because 'research' doesn't get you anywhere any longer on Macs.  I'll explain.  There used to be a time when everything worked out of the box on OSX.  This was probably up to Tiger.  Then, up to, say, El Capitan you could do 'research,' and make things work.  But now things have got so bad -- see what people are writing/asking on discussions.apple.com -- that your research will lead you to think 'x' will work on one of the newer OSXs -- but it won't, and you'll be having to jump through hoops hopelessly trying to make things work.   That's why now it's a better idea to ask other users.

Comment: In other words, instead of trusting Macs anymore (even Canon and Brother retail printing departments are becoming indifferent to OSX or leery about it, if you've noticed) and trusting 'official information,' it is smarter to get a 'Yes, this works,' or 'No, it doesn't work' from users who've been there, done that.  OSX users can't keep behaving like we used to; we have to adapt to the sharp changes in how Apple sees OSX vis-a-vis its other products.

Comment: Why do you need a printer at all for paperless fax sending/receiving?

Comment: There is no vendor that keeps a list of hardware that works or not.  [Microsoft only certifies drivers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/whql-release-signature#:~:text=%20Obtaining%20a%20WHQL%20release%20signature%20consists%20of,WHQL%20release%20signature%20for%20the%20driver...%20More%20) and Apple only now requires App notarization but neither ever had a list of compatible peripheral devices.  It’s your job to check the product page to see if they say its compatible

Comment: For nohillside. First, I need a printer for printing, and the 'printer' I'd like is a convenient all-in-one.  Next, re your question, I suppose you are alluding to those online fax services.  They're not remotely a substitute for realy faxing because, among several drawbacks, they overcharge and they serve only some countries of the world out of nearly 200. So what I want to do is use a phone-line like I used to with OSs on PowerBook G4s on which we had brilliant FAXstf, rely on my phone-line, pay a low price, and be able to fax to any old country.

Comment: For Allan.  Yes, I checked Epson's product pages and know what's compatible and what's not but, if you will re-read my question, you will see that it's not about compatibility at all.  And the only Epson all-in-ones I found say nothing about paperless faxing; as such, what are those paperless faxing apps in the subdir I mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick search of the Epson site, it looks like only two models still have Fax (that's usually that few multifunction printers still include.

I found this model:  WorkForce Pro WF-3733 All-in-One Printer

There is also a WF-3730 ... I'm not sure what the difference is between the 3733 and the 3730.

I have an (old) Epson Artisan 837 which has all those features, but while that printer is no longer produced, Epson has been updating the drivers for it ... I was still able to get the driver for Catalina.

These days I'm not so much a fan of Inkjets (with except of some professional photo printers that use pigment based inks) and prefer color lasers (which have really come down in price).  But this bias because I'm tired of inkjet printheads drying up and wasting a lot of ink trying to clear the head.  If the printer is used frequently enough, it's not really an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info.  However, my question is about using the built-in Epson software and apps that I mentioned to do paperless faxing, and wanting to know which Epson all-in-ones support this.